# ReferenceError: self is not defined using React-Pixi and Next-urql

Tags: reactjs, next.js, pixi.js, urql

I keep getting this error when using the Next-Urql and React-Pixi. I understand that this is because React-Pixi requires WEB APIs.

> Server Error
>
> ReferenceError: self is not defined This error happened while
> generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the
> terminal window.

**This is my code:**

```
import { Graphics, Stage } from "@inlet/react-pixi";
import { withUrqlClient } from "next-urql";
import { createUrqlClient } from "../../../utils/urqlUtils/createUrqlClient";
import NoSSR from "react-no-ssr";
const edit = () => {
....
  
  return (
    <Layout metaTags={metaTags}>
      <Flex flexDir="row">
            {typeof window !== "undefined" && (
          <NoSSR>

              <Stage>
                <Graphics
                  draw={(g) => {
                    g.beginFill(0xff3300);
                    g.lineStyle(4, 0xffd900, 1);

                    g.moveTo(50, 50);
                    g.lineTo(250, 50);
                    g.lineTo(100, 100);
                    g.lineTo(50, 50);
                    g.endFill();

                    g.lineStyle(2, 0x0000ff, 1);
                    g.beginFill(0xff700b, 1);
                    g.drawRect(50, 250, 120, 120);

                    g.lineStyle(2, 0xff00ff, 1);
                    g.beginFill(0xff00bb, 0.25);
                    g.drawRoundedRect(150, 450, 300, 100, 15);
                    g.endFill();

                    g.lineStyle(0);
                    g.beginFill(0xffff0b, 0.5);
                    g.drawCircle(470, 90, 60);
                    g.endFill();
                  }}
                />
              </Stage>
              </NoSSR>
            )}
          </Flex>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default withUrqlClient(createUrqlClient, { ssr: false })(edit);
```

I understand that I should use dynamic rendering, but when I do I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're using Next.js by saying that `self` it not available on server side [globalThis MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis#description)

You could found a related issue on [react pixi repo](https://github.com/inlet/react-pixi/issues/287). Supposedly, you can try import [no SSR](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) Next.js.

```js
// Separate your pixi into a component and import
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const PixiComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/your-pixi-component'),
  { ssr: false }
)

return (
  ...
    <PixiComponentWithNoSSR />
  ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I imported the **react-no-ssr** library and wrapped the components in the <NoSSR></NoSSR> tags, but I keep getting the same error.

I've updated my response to show what my code looks like.

Comment: @jmecs Could you try this [workaround](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/using-client-side-only-packages/#workaround-4-use-reactlazy-and-suspense-on-client-side-only). As the author mentioned in [this ticket](https://github.com/inlet/react-pixi/issues/233) you can try to find dynamic import either Gatsbyjs or Nextjs

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. For reference I used this article:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr